# Limit which tools are available in Kendo UI Editor

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-editor

I have the following code....

```
<textarea name="description" data-role="editor" class="k-textbox" data-bind="value:description"></textarea>
```

This produces a kendo editor in place of the textarea and all is fine except I would like to limit the tools available.

As it is I have:
Bold, Italic, Underline, Strikethrough, Left Justified, Right Justified, Central Justified, Justified, Ordered List, Unordered List, Indent, Outdent, Link, Unlink and Table creator/editor.

I just need Bold, Italic, Underline, Ordered List, Unordered List, Indent, Outdent, Link, Unlink and Table creator/editor.

How to I achieve this.... Note I have had to use the **data-role="editor"** method as the textarea if within a **kendo editor template**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the [tools](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/editor#configuration-tools) options.

It seems like you're using [MVVM](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/editor/mvvm), so you can probably set it up to be like:

```
<textarea name="description" class="k-textbox"
    data-role="editor"
    data-tools="['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'insertOrderedList', 'insertUnorderedList', 'indent', 'outdent', 'createLink', 'unlink', 'createTable', 'addColumnLeft', 'addColumnRight', 'addRowAbove', 'addRowBelow', 'deleteRow', 'deleteColumn']"
    data-bind="value:description"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

using the textarea will insert an iframe. You can use div instead of that. In both the cases we can manipulate tools in the editor like

```
                    <div id="topEditor"></div>
                    <div class="column"></div>



                    $("#topEditor").kendoEditor({
                    tools: [
                        "bold",
                        "italic",
                        "underline",
                        "strikethrough",
                        "justifyLeft",
                        "justifyCenter",
                        "justifyRight",
                        "justifyFull",
                        "createLink",
                        "unlink",
                        "insertImage",
                        "createTable",
                        "addColumnLeft",
                        "addColumnRight",
                        "addRowAbove",
                        "addRowBelow",
                        "deleteRow",
                        "deleteColumn",
                        "foreColor",
                        "backColor"
                    ]
                });

                $(".column").kendoEditor({
                    tools: [
                        "bold",
                        "italic",
                        "underline",
                        "createLink",
                        "unlink",
                        "insertImage"
                    ]
                });
```